Where in the Ramayana is it said that all the gods worship sage Agastya while the sage himself worships Śiva alone?
Śrī Appayya Dīkṣita mentions this in his Rāmāyaṇa-tātparya-sārasaṃgraha-stotra. It is apparently from the Rāmāyaṇa verses in the Araṇyakāṇḍa.
But where exactly is it said that all the gods worship Agastya, who worships Shiva?

In the Valmiki Ramayana Critical Edition of Aranya Kanda, are present the following verses, when Lord Rama enters the hermitage of Agastya -

3011015a taṁ śiṣyaḥ praśritaṁ vākyam agastyavacanaṁ bruvan


3011015c prāveśayad yathānyāyaṁ satkārārthaṁ susatkr̥tam


3011016a praviveśa tato rāmaḥ sītayā sahalakṣmaṇaḥ


3011016c praśāntahariṇākīrṇam āśramaṁ hy avalokayan


3011017a sa tatra brahmaṇaḥ sthānam agneḥ sthānaṁ tathaiva ca


3011017c viṣṇoḥ sthānaṁ mahendrasya sthānaṁ caiva vivasvataḥ


3011018a somasthānaṁ bhagasthānaṁ sthānaṁ kauberam eva ca


3011018c dhātur vidhātuḥ sthānaṁ ca vāyoḥ sthānaṁ tathaiva ca


The disciple honoured him and repeated Agastya’s words. He welcomed them hospitably, following the proper rites, and made the deserving ones enter. Rama entered, with Sita and Lakshmana, and saw the hermitage, which was full of truculent deer. They progressively passed through Brahma’s place, Agni’s place, Vishnu’s place, the great Indra’s place, Vivasvat’s (sun) place, Soma’s place, Bhaga’s place, Kubera’s place, Dhatri–Vidhatri’s place and Vayu’s place.

These places (sthAnams) in the hermitage of Agastya, implies that Agastya probably worshipped all the above mentioned Gods.
Now, the question is -

The Rāmāyaṇa verses in Araṇyakāṇḍa where it is said that all the gods worship sage Agastya while the sage himself worships Śiva alone?

I tried searching but I was able to find only the first part of the above in the Critical Edition.

3010087a atra devāḥ sagandharvāḥ siddhāś ca paramarṣayaḥ


3010087c agastyaṁ niyatāhāraṁ satataṁ paryupāsate


The gods, the gandharvas, the siddhas and the supreme rishis always worship Agastya, who is restrained in diet, here.


I haven't found that either
